# Custom word 2007 headings not showing in outline view or document map

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

My company has created custom word styles for headings that I am supposed to use in my documents.

There are two problem I'm experiencing with the custom headings:

- they do not show properly in outline view or document map, making large documents very difficult to navigate when editing them.
- the headings do get added as bookmarks to exported PDFs

**Question**: How can I fix the custom headings so that they still have the same corporate look and feel styling, but show up in outline view and document map?

---

The standard word heading style "Heading 1" is here:

[image: standard word headings]

My company's version of the heading style "Heading 1" is here:

[image: custom word headings]

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to [Adam's answer](https://superuser.com/a/660923/200797), I now fix up my documents with the following macro:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1. Numbered").ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel1
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2. Numbered").ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel2
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3. Numbered").ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel3
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4. Numbered").ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel4
ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 5. Numbered").ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevel5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the Outline option under paragraph formatting to "Level 1" for your custom style to appear in the navigation pane.

Comment: For anybody who would like to see screenshots (in german) they can take a look at [Option 2 changing outline lelvel](http://superuser.com/questions/810243/how-to-add-custom-styles-to-navigation-pane-or-change-them-with-vba/810266#810266)